# Missing Purpose String in Info.plist while uploading app to testlight with a localized app

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have added the required permission in info.plist with the variable name as the strings are localized to multiple languages.

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(NSCameraUsageDescription)</string>
```

I have also added the translated string to the infoPlist.strings as

`NSCameraUsageDescription" = "App wants to user your camera to scan the bill and scan the QR code";`

This works perfectly while running the app however, shows the missing purpose string error while uploading the app in testflight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>App wants to user your camera to scan the bill and scan the QR code</string>
```

infoPlist.strings:

```
NSCameraUsageDescription" = "App wants to user your camera to scan the bill and scan the QR code";
```